# Get selected items from checkbox list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How to get the selected items values of checkBoxList in button click event in jquery...

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="check_list" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text ="One" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text ="Two" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text ="Three" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
<input type="button" id="btn_click" value="Click"/>
```

Comment: Do you already tried do write something? Can you post your javascript code?

Comment: Always a good idea to show what you've tried already. `$('#check_list').val()` should do it

Comment: oops didn't read question properly. `$('#btn_click').click(function() { $('#check_list').val() });`

Comment: ignore my comments above, my eyes/brain malfunctioned : )

Answer (score 1):

just use an attribute selector like
On click of button you can loop trough all checked values like

```
  $("#btn_click").click(function(){
    $("[id*=check_list] input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
           // add $(this).val() to your array
      });
    });
```

Comment: wont work - it's a select not an input. not my downvote!

Comment: Checkbox will evaluate to the input control when page rendered in HTML.

Comment: @Dave, it's not a `<select>`. It is a list of `<input type="checkbox">` elements (your may be confusing `<asp:CheckBoxList>` with `<asp:DropDownList>`. That code won't work because it assumes the same `id` is used for all the check boxes, which is wrong.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi so it is!! That means I didn't read it property - twice.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Updated to consider the id's which will start with the common id as the main server control. [Here is working example](http://www.jqueryfaqs.com/Articles/ASP.Net-CheckBoxList-Get-Checked-or-Selected-Items-Client-side-using-jQuery.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

See the jQuery `:checked` selector as described in the [API](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).